# PHP Traits: define property and error "definition differs"

Tags: php, traits

I have the following code and it works correctly:

```
abstract class ParentClass
{
    public $flag = true;
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public $flag = false;
}

var_dump((new ChildClass())->flag); // false
```

But if I use Trait it leads to Fatal Error

> ParentClass and TFlag define the same property ($flag) in the composition of ChildClass. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed in...`

```
abstract class ParentClass
{
    public $flag = true;
}

trait TFlag
{
    public $flag = false;
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    use TFlag;
}

var_dump((new ChildClass())->flag);
```

**UPDATED**:

It tested on PHP 7.1, 7.2, 7.4

Why is the following definition compatible for class inheritance and for logic, but not incompatible for trait?

- public $flag = true;
- public $flag = false;

**UPDATED**

I can override a method but not a property (it works):

```
abstract class ParentClass
{
    public function flag(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}

trait TFlag
{
    public function flag(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    use TFlag;
}

var_dump((new ChildClass())->flag()); // false
```

Comment: What's your exact question? Why not avoid such a situation if it throws an error?

Comment: Magnus Eriksson, trait it copy-paste to ChildClass. And I can override a method, see update

Comment: You haven't changed the methods signature though.

Comment: Yes I cannot change signature for inheritance. But I didn't change signature for property it yet public bool.

Comment: Exactly two years gone and no answer yet. So, it could be a bug...

Comment: It's not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP Documentation is explicit about this (examples 12 and 13).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.properties

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility and initial value), otherwise a fatal error is issued.